# Can't get input stream from URL! Java

Tags: java, netbeans, user-agent

I have the following simple program which reads an image from a url.

```
public class TestWebScrapper {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        URL imageUrl;
        try {
            imageUrl = new URL("https://assets.boxdice.com.au/bj_corporate/listings/1751/4618116b.jpg");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
                    connection.setRequestProperty(
                            "User-Agent",
                            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0");
            BufferedImage propertImage = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestWebScrapper.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

}
```

The issue that I have this is that this gives an exception

> Can't get input stream from URL!

with an message:

> Received fatal alert: internal_error

I tried adding the user-agent, but the issue persists. The link works fine on a browser. 
This error comes only for images from this url, but does anyone know how to work around this?

Comment: Did you meant to pass `connection` to `ImageIO.read`, because that object has the edited uer agent?

Comment: http vs https or HttpUrlConnection vs HttsUrlConnection

Comment: @simar do i have to use HttpsUrlConnection to get images from an https webserver? If so do I need a check to see if the url is https ot http?
Or does it get handled?

Comment: Not necessary, depend on how webserver configured. But if  access to https then use HttpsUrlConnection.

Comment: Image u are tring to download from assets.boxdice.com.au available over http and https. But if website configured to use only https u might be getting  an error.

Answer (score 3):

You set the `User-Agent` on the connection but then use the `imageUrl`  to load the image, so this has no effect.

Use

```
BufferedImage propertImage = ImageIO.read(connection.getInputStream());
```

instead (and close the inputstream once you are done).