# Can't get input stream from url error java

Tags: java, image, selenium-webdriver, image-processing, phantomjs

I made a program in selenium that extracts links of some images from a website so after extraction of link i wanted to save all those images in a folder so i wrote a little code for that

```
for(int j=0; j<links.size(); j++) {
                 URL imageURL = new URL(linklist[j]);
                 BufferedImage saveImage = ImageIO.read(imageURL);
                 ImageIO.write(saveImage, "png", new File("C:\\Users\\Dumpty\\Desktop\\Output\\logo-forum"+ j +".png"));
        }
```

and yeah im using array to store the url's and for confirmation i printed all the links with this code

```
for(int k=0; k<links.size(); k++) {
            System.out.println(linklist[k]);
        }
```

all seems to be working fine but in extraction im facing problem, im getting
**Can't get input stream from URL!** Error
I also tried this
[Can't get input stream from URL! Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35430198/cant-get-input-stream-from-url-java)
but it's still not working
this is the full view of the error im getting

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't get input stream from URL!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.phantomjs.phantomJStest.main(phantomJStest.java:58)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/f_kendBNnYqba-mMV-3ItGZ2zzbChaaV22nE4uaEW92EWtXPzvFYwDk82AKQ6YlOru4=w1440-h620 2x
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it has nothing to do with your code. If you **fully read** the exception message, you have the solution there.

Check what a [400 HTTP error is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors). It is a bad request from your client, it looks like the URL you are asking is malformed, as it contains a space. You can try to [URL encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Character_data) your `imageURL` input.